# How do I get that $11^{35} \equiv 6 \hspace{0.1cm} \text{mod} (13)$ from $11^{36} \equiv 1 \hspace{0.1cm} \text{mod} (13)$

Tags: modular-arithmetic

I have no clue how to do this, I manage to get I get that $11^{36} \equiv 1  \hspace{0.1cm} \text{mod} (13)$ but I can't get anywhere from there.

Comment: $\!\large\bmod 13\!:\ 11\cdot 11^{35}\equiv 1 \iff 11^{35}\equiv \dfrac{1}{11}\equiv \dfrac{-12}{-2}\equiv 6\ $ by methods  in the linked dupes $\ \ $

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $11^{36}=1$ in $\Bbb Z/13$, then $11^{35}=11^{-1}$. But since $6\cdot 11=66=1$ in $\Bbb Z/13$, we have $11^{-1}=6$.

Here I just write $a=b$ in the ring $\Bbb Z/n$ for $a\equiv b\bmod n$, so that we see it a bit easier.
For $n=13$, $\Bbb Z/n$ is a field and all nonzero elements have an inverse.

Comment: Take a look at the exercise from the angle where you don't know that the result is 6, think of it as if you only knew that 11^36 == 1 (mod 13) and you need to find out the result of 11^35 == r (mod 13)

Comment: That's what I did. Just multiply the equation $11^{36}=1$ by $11^{-1}$, which is $6$. You know, $11^{36}\cdot 11^{-1}=11^{35}$.

Comment: Okay, thanks <3

Answer (score 1):

All you need to know for this is that, since $13$ is a prime number, $\mathbb{Z} / 13 \mathbb{Z}$ is a **field**.

In particular, every non zero element has a unique inverse for multiplication. Constating that
$$11 \times 6 = 66 \equiv 1 \hspace{0.1cm} \text{mod} (13)$$
it turns out that the multiplicative inverse of $11$ is $6$ : $\boxed{11^{-1} \equiv 6}$.

Now, since you know that $11^{36} \equiv 1 \hspace{0.1cm} \text{mod} (13)$, it turns out that :

$$11^{35} \equiv 11^{36} \times 11^{-1} \equiv 1 \times 6 \equiv 6 \hspace{0.1cm} \text{mod} (13)$$

Answer (score 0):

What were your efforts ? However, if you proved that $11^{36} \equiv 1 \hspace{0.1cm} (13)$ then you have that $11^{35}\cdot 11 \equiv 1 \hspace{0.1cm}(13)$. In this line it is written that $11^{35}$ is the inverse of $11$ by definition, by uniqueness you only have to prove that $6$ does the same job, i.e $6 \cdot 11 \overset{?}{\equiv} 1 \hspace{0.1cm}(13)$, which is true, and you have the desired result.

Comment: Originally, I didn't know the result is 6, I had to look into the key. So I wanted to know how to get it only knowing that 11^36 == 1 mod(13)

Comment: @OgnjenOgnjanovic It doesn't change the fact that $11^{35}$ is the inverse of $11$, so you're searching for an $x$ such that $11 \cdot x \equiv 1 \hspace{0.1cm} (13)$

Answer (score 0):

Use this relation:

$6\times 11-5\times 13=1$

So we can write:

$$11^{36}\equiv (6\times 11-5\times 13=1) \ mod (13) \equiv 6 \times 11\ mod (13)$$

Therefore:

$11^{36}\equiv 6\times 11 \ mod(13)$

Dividing both sides by 11 we get:

$11^{35} \equiv 6 \ mod(13)$

Answer (score 0):

The exercise here is to calculate the [multiplicative inverse](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiplicative_inverse) of $11$, written $11^{-1}$, in $\bmod 13$ arithmetic. Then we can get that since $11^{36}\equiv 1$, we will have $11^{35}\equiv 11^{36}\cdot 11^{-1}\equiv 11^{-1}\bmod 13$

Now $13$ and $11$ are coprime (of course, since $13$ is prime) so it's guaranteed that there is a value $a$ such that $11a \equiv 1 \bmod 13$. For a small number like $13$, it's not too hard to find this by guessing, but the [extended Euclidean algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_Euclidean_algorithm) will find the value rapidly for less straightforward cases.

To show the logic of this algorithm, we find progressively smaller results which we can make with linear combinations of $13$ & $11$ until we make $1$:
\begin{align}1\cdot 13 + 0\cdot 11  &= 13 \tag{setup: 1}\\
0\cdot 13 + 1\cdot 11 &= 11 \tag{setup: 2}\\
1\cdot 13 + -1\cdot 11 &= 2 \tag{(1)-(2): 3 }\\
-5\cdot 13 + 6\cdot 11 &= 1 \tag{(2)-5(3): result }\\\end{align}
gives us that $6\cdot 11 \equiv 1$ so $11^{-1}\equiv 6 \bmod 13$.